# Find all rectangular subset of Python matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list

I've created a python matrix using this code:

`matrix = [[0 for i in xrange(N)] for i in xrange(N)]`

where N is the size I want. How can I get all possible rectangular subsections that contain the top-left corner from this array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you define rectangle in your case?

Comment: @Xlee As any set of consecutive elements that form a rectangle

Comment: With the top-left corner as vertex, there would be N**2 - 1 rectangles?